# What is the PostgreSQL equivalent to mysql_result()

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

I looked around and couldn't find it! Maybe I didn't look hard enough,but this website has people who can give quick answers

I'm running PHP5 and PostgreSQL 9.1

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[pg_fetch_result](http://php.net/pg_fetch_result) or [pg_fetch_array](http://php.net/pg_fetch_result) should do the trick for you, depending on the exact need.